# Scientifically testing segulos

Tags: science, segulah

I'm wondering whether anyone has done any scientific tests to establish whether any specific segulos have any statistically significant effect.  Has anyone come across anything like this?

Comment: If any had actually been found successful you can be confident we'd have all heard about it.

Comment: Segulos are part of the physical and spiritual world. The word "segula" appears in Shemos 19:5 in reference to the Jewish people. Rashi translates the word as meaning: a precious treasure house. It refers to something valuable and hidden from the eye, kept for special purposes. Usually segulos consist of reminders to make you daven to and reconfirm belief in Hashem. There are physical segulos as in, certain foods — that might be studied. Though even then, it all depends if hashem deems you worthy. That is the only reason it will work. ...

Comment: The zohar mentions that some segulos are tied to the spiritual reality, though even then that doesn't mean it's a given that the segula will work. It's all up to hashem and the merit of the person. Simply put, how can you relate segulos with science ?

Comment: @Shababnik eg. if you choose a population of Jewish people which has a statistically significant size and randomly allocate them into 4 groups - 1 doing nothing, 1 doing a real segulah, 1 doing a fake segulah and 1 davening with heartfelt tefillah, if the sample size is large enough then you are likely to end up with roughly the same number of meritorious people in each group.  Then you can measure the outcome of the 4 groups to see which method is most effective, and you have baselines of people doing nothing plus the fake segulah as a placebo (some complications to overcome there though)

Comment: @MosesSupposes I'm no prophet, but Hashem will probably scew the results, to show that one shouldn't rely on segulos. I'm basing this off shulchan Aruch — one shouldn't think his 'concentration' during teffilah is what made hashem answer the prayer. Also, how are you to judge who is righteous?

Comment: @Shababnik well it would be interesting to find out, and I'm sure that the Shulchan Aruch isn't saying that our tefillah has no effect. I'm not judging who is righteous, that’s the point in a large sample size and selecting at random as you should get a roughly even distribution of righteousness that way.

Comment: @MosesSupposes. Well I wish you luck with your experiment then

Comment: @Shababnik I don't quite have the budget for it!  I was just wondering if anyone has tried anything like it

Comment: @MosesSupposes I just remembered that some sefarim when writing about segulos write "בדוק ומנוסה" which means tried and tested. I can't vouch for their use of the scientific process, but I think that's the best you're gonna get

Comment: God is not statistical. What are the chances your bashert happens to be frum?

Comment: @shmosel I don't think that's a good example.  Why are you assuming that your bashert would be totally random otherwise? Finding a spouse is bound to be biased towards a similar culture, a relatively local area geographically etc. even without the concept of a bashert

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on what your definition of "scientifically tested" is.

In general, scientific testing means that a given procedure is recorded with purported results and that the process and results are repeatable by others.

There is a book written by Rabbi Chaim Vital called [Sefer HaPa'ulot](https://www.hbooks.co.il/product/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA--%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90%D7%9C) ספר הפעולות which does precisely this. Rabbi Vital tested many segulot and refu'ot precisely and reported whether they actually did what was reported or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big segula person but such a study  would be impossible. There would be the issue of testing Hashem that would disallow such a study.

Even if that could be worked around. Trying to analyze segulas  from  a scientific acceptable perspective is like trying to fit  a square peg in a round hole. Those who are trying to prove the efficacy of seulos usually use anecdotal data. Scientists  usually do not accept such evidence.  Moreover there are unknown spiritual factors behind a segulah so in theory it would be possible for a segula to work even though those who followed it seemed   statistically less  likely to have seen a benefit than those who did not. The segula proponent explanation would be that the unknown spiritual  factors caused that outcome. Conversly if the segulas would show a statistical benefit then the scientists  would be the ones insisting that the result is only becuase of unknown other factors

Comment: I think it would be possible to set up a randomised double-blind trial, but it would be quite difficult.  For a start, it would be difficult to find people who don't know about the segula and would accept a made up placebo as a baseline

Comment: Except Maaser there we can test

Comment: "There would be the issue of testing Hashem that would disallow such a study." Do you have a source for the claim that testing the efficacy of a segulah would constitute "testing God" and as such halakhically forbidden?

Comment: I'm inclined to think that testing the segulah is not the same as testing Hashem.  I'm more interested in whether any segulahs can be shown to be more effective than heartfelt tefillah

Comment: @MosesSupposes segulos are meant to remind you to pray

Comment: @Shababnik that often doesn't seem to be the way that people use them. A lot of people think they are some kind of magical shortcut

Comment: @MosesSupposes I daresay some people don't know what they're doing.

Comment: @Shababnik Yup, and that's before thinking about the ones that come from avoda zara